# give background shadow for text present on image

Tags: html, css

we have images in our site as below

[image]

at the bottom of the image we are displaying text , we want to give background shadow for that text as below :

[image]

```
.fanbook-img img {
    width: 100% !important;
}

    img {
        display: block;
    }

    , *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: try to give Background on text....

Comment: This question is about basic CSS. Cool that you're learning! But could be good to study up on a training website - W3Schools has some simple ones, Codecademy has good tutorials

Comment: @BalvantAhir Thanks for support.

Comment: @henry yes, i am beginner in css, i will follow your words. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I haven't actually used this myself, but maybe check out https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web - you might even be able to jump straight to Unit 4 (but it's just 7 hours… could just spend a week doing the whole thing:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your css. See teh below css code .

```
.fanbook-name {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* add this */
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.fanbook-name b {
    /* bottom: 25px; */
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* position: relative; */
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.fanbook-image li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1%; /* change this */
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    position: relative; /* add this */
    width: 24%;
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: What have you done? Why not explain the reasoning? It is obvious the OP is not that experienced yet, so a 'try this' does not really help anyone.

Comment: @somethinghere sorry i am not good in css, please suggest me better one.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe The reason I am saying that is because the answer explains nothing - it works, but have you learned anything? Because if you are just copying the answer instead of learning from it it is not a good answer. (I am referring to this answer, you question was fine, I just think there were people who have helped you more on this thread more deserving of the reputation)

Answer (score 3):

HTML -

```
<div id="img"><div id="text"><p>text </p></div><div>
```

CSS-

```
#img{
background-image: url('');
}
#text{
background-color: rgba(?,?,?,0.5);
padding: 10px 10px;
margin: 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The text and whole thing needs to be in some html element, for example the HTML

```
<p>text</p>
```

which will then get the CSS

```
p {
    display: block;
    padding: [vertical padding] [horizontal padding];
    background: [background color, in rgba];
}
```

The `display: block` makes it full-width and makes it take padding. Just to give you an example of working CSS, here are so sample values:

```
p {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

The `background` is an rgba ("red green blue alpha") value in order to give you transparency. Hex values, the other common way of writing colors for the web (they look like "#ff00ff"), don't support transparency. r, g, and b are 0 (none) to 255 (full), and a is 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque); the example is half-opaque white (`rgba(0,0,0,.5)` would be half-opaque black).

Note that the `p` in `p {...}` in the CSS is targeting the `<p>..</p>` in the HTML - if you were wrapping the text in some other element, you'd use that in the CSS instead. Targeting a "bare" selector can be risky, because those styles will apply to *every* instance of it. To be safer, can also target a class or id, instead of the element name. For example

```
HTML

    <p class="text-with-transparent-background">
        text
    </p>

CSS

    .text-with-transparent-background {
        ...(styles as above)...
    }
```

A `class` can be reused multiple times on a single page. An `id` (HTML `<elementname id="yourcustomidname">...</elementname>`, CSS `#yourcustomidname {...styles...}`) can only be used once per page

Comment: Since the user is obviously not that good at css yet, I find it risky your pseudo code is lacking a selector... Your example uses a `<p>` so why not use that selector as well?

Comment: @somethinghere I don't feel it would be appropriate to be more specific, given the little information provided in the question. It's very possible the text is already wrapped in some element, and as a beginner the OP might `<p>` itself was necessary. Judging from the code provided in the question, the OP knows to preface the styles with the target selector, but I'll edit to add that in

Comment: I mostly said it because you are also using a p tag in your example :) could be confusing, but hey, its not a bad answer! Certainly worth a +1.

Comment: @somethinghere @ nsdlfefinedieicbe I've filled this out with a lot more to give a (very brief:) overview of elements, classes, ids, and rgba.

Comment: Yeah well done! I have already cast my vote on this one, but good job on improving it!

Comment: and now added some working css. hahaha I better stop

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="fanbook-img">
        <a href="http://sb.kidsdial.com/white-marble-2-samsung-galaxy-j7-phone-case.html">
           <div class="">texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext</div>
            <img style="width:250px;height:250px;text-align:center;" src="http://sb.kidsdial.com/media/FanBook/iQdzXDrvEU.jpg">
</a>
 </div>

    .fanbook-img > a {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .fanbook-img div {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        bottom: 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        height: auto;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 99;
    }
```

Comment: What have you done? Why not explain the reasoning? It is obvious the OP is not that experienced yet, so a 'try this' does not really help anyone.

Comment: Thanks for support. as other user answer helped me only with css i accepted that